# SQL Server 2014 SP1 Setup Freezes Removing Temporary Files On Windows 10 x64

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation, windows-10

I want to install *SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition with Service Pack 1* on Windows 10. But when I try, the installation stops every time at the part the screenshot below shows, and I wait for hours. Finally, I have to cancel the setup process.

[image: Setup Screenshot]

I did some research into the issue, then installed Entity Framework 3.5 and Windows PowerShell 2.0**. I needed no pre-requisites.

Please note that I also could not install *Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081438)*. This update fails to install on my computer the same thing every time. Maybe this problem can be resolved by this update; because I heard that this update is also related to Entity Framework?

What is the reason for this problem? What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You are installing *SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition* on Windows 10 (a client OS), which is not supported. If you were to take this case to Microsoft they would say you are trying an unsupported scenario. Although your installation won't fail as such if you are trying to install Enterprise Edition on a client OS, what is the point in wasting such a costly license on a client OS which has so many limitations, compared with a server OS?

The Log you posted is incomplete. You can use [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.120).aspx) to locate all the log files regarding installation, then post it on on shared drive for analysis. Please share the link with us so that we can study the logs.

Answer (score 2):

I installed *SQL Server Developer Edition (x64)* instead, and in the end it worked! I have successfully setup this edition.

Actually, the key point is the part of *Feature Selection*. If you click **Select All** option at Feature Selection, this installation will probably fail. At least, it has failed for me (using a Client OS).

Instead of this, you should select these features according to your requirements. On this point, Shanky is right: I suppose the problem was related to Client OS versus Server OS. I selected features as shown below:

[image: Features Selection]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Open Task Manager and you should notice 3 instances of Windows Installer running.  End Task the first two instances and your installation should continue and complete successfully.

Comment: How do you decide which are the first two?

Answer (score 0):

When killing the first and second process, you can determine which processes are first by the process ID (PID) in task manager. The PID column is not shown by default, you need to add it to your view in the Processes tab. Lower is older, higher is newer.